# Chrome Safety Warning lookalike-url

Tags: subdomain, domain-authority

Our 3rd party subdomain website, is getting flagged by Chrome as a lookalike-url

example-ca.libcal.com

I have found no official documentation about this besides the Chrome flags to Enable it, (it was first released in 2019 as an experimental feature)

Is there something like a canonical tag I could use to verify its authenticity...

Anyone have this problem before?

Comment: Does this help? https://support.google.com/domains/answer/3530994

Comment: will try it out!